# sResNotFound Undeclared identifier in Delphi 2009

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-5

While converting my Delphi 5 code to Delphi 2009 got the following error. "sResNotFound Undeclared identifier".

In Delphi 5, sResNotFound is included in Consts.pas. Any one have idea for newer Delphi version which file i should include in uses clause.

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constant is defined in the `RTLConsts` unit.